# Valid array gives php Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have the following foreach loop that gives me the invalid argument error:

```
$all_students = $this -> model_accounts -> get_students_on_account($account['account_id']);

        foreach ($all_students as $student)
        {                               
            ...
        }
```

I tried to debug using print_r to check what the $all_students array looks like and I got this as a result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 00062
            [student_name] => Reckless
            [student_surname] => Harmse
            [acc_id] => 198
            [dob] => 07-07-1993
            [gender] => Male
            [active] => 1
            [has_pic] => 1
            [avatar] => 106.jpg
            [pic_ver] => 1
            [student_identity_num] => 9307075052084
        )

)
```

So the array is there and as seen in the print_r details, it is seen as an array.

I have looked at other similar questions and none of them could help.

Thanx in advance

Added:
Model function used to get the students

```
function get_students_on_account($account_id)
{
    $data = '';     
    $this->db->where('acc_id', $account_id);
    $q = $this->db->get('students');

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($q->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $row['dob'] = $this -> change_date_format($row['dob']);
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Could you double check the *print_r* output is indeed like that, right before the `foreach`? It seems to me that *$all_students* is reset to *null* somewhere before the `foreach`. Also, it could be helpful for you to note for which *account_id* the problem occurs, and for which it doesn't.

Comment: get_students_on_account
could you please post your method

Comment: @trincot i loop through all the accounts, so it does not give this to a specific account, but every time its ran

Comment: @santosh I have added the model function used

Comment: @trincot I get the $all_students data directly before I do the loop, so there is nothing that should reset the array

Comment: The model function returns an empty string sometimes, that will cause problems. It should never return a string, but always an array.

Comment: just to be sure: are you sure you have the right code line? is there a nested foreach within your outer foreach? or the other way, is this snippet part of a larger loop, so that you may get some valid and some invalid values for `$all_students` ?

Comment: The students loop is nested within the accounts loop, and for each account, the all_students array is cleared, the get_account_students is a tested function that I use in another controller, so I do get the correct and valid data, but for some reason the students foreach loop gave the error...however the question has been answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**In Controller**

```
$all_students = $this->model_accounts->get_students_on_account($account['account_id']);

if($all_students == false){
    echo "Empty result";
}
else{
    foreach ($all_students[0] as $student)
    {                               
        ...
    }
}
```

**In Model**

```
function get_students_on_account($account_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE acc_id = $account_id");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result);

    if (empty($count)) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: @RickusHarmse  Check now

Comment: this gives this error `Uninitialized string offset: 0`, I have added my model function above

Comment: i have chnage model. change that

Comment: Gives the original error again, so I don't think the error is with the model function

Comment: @RickusHarmse check now. Some bugs fixed and now it should wrk

Comment: It went further than it used to, just gives another error, but this is the closest I have come to correct,,,but not sure why you said " can you specify why. Dont be funny"

Comment: @RickusHarmse happy to help :)

Comment: yes, think the internet went down and did not save my response, I removed the IF statement and now it works fine, no error and gives the correct data on the users side, thanx

Comment: @RickusHarmse ok ok. free to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

In your function *get_students_on_account*, replace this:

```
$data = '';
```

by this:

```
$data = array();
```

This is needed to consistently return an array. You don't want to return a string. When it does, the problem that you described will occur.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$res = $q->result_array();    
foreach ($res as &$row)
{
    $row['dob'] = $this -> change_date_format($row['dob']);
}
return $res;
```